# Codeigniter URL Pattern using htaccess / route / model

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've just put my hands on MVC and new to Codeigniter.

As per my understanding Codeigniter url consist of (base url) / Class / Method

I am trying some more complex url structure as
www.example.com/listing/category/country/state/city/listing-id-23
which I presume can be achieved by calling one controller from another, or may be through routes.

PS, category/country/state/city here changes dynamically based on product.

Is it possible to have url like that with Codeigniter or do I have to stick with www.example.com/listing/listing-id-23 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URI helper class for that.

$this->uri->segment(n)

Permits you to retrieve a specific segment. Where n is the segment number you wish to retrieve. Segments are numbered from left to right. For example, if your full URL is this:

http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up

The segment numbers would be this:

news
local
metro
crime_is_up

By default the function returns FALSE (boolean) if the segment does not exist. There is an optional second parameter that permits you to set your own default value if the segment is missing. For example, this would tell the function to return the number zero in the event of failure:

$product_id = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html